# Besides the USO, were there other organizations in New York City during WWll that provided entertainment for the troops?

Tags: world-war-two, new-york, entertainment

I know the USO had the Stage Door canteen in NYC during the war, but were there other organizations that hosted dances/concerts at less permanent venues like at armories or community centers around the city? According to info from uso.org, they had Mobile USO services, but with the canteen, I don't know that they'd do that in NYC. So my question is, what other organizations provided entertainment for the troops and where in the city would it occur?

When I say entertainment, I mean canteen type activities (singer, band, performer), but at a larger venue.

Comment: It might be useful if you define the scope of the "entertainment" you're interested in.

Comment: Consider the The Soldiers’, Sailors’, Marines’, Coast Guard and Airmen’s Club, since 1919 continues to fulfill its mission, as the only private organization in the New York area .See: http://ssmaclub.org/.  They put on a big clambake & beer shindig, with a dance, in 1967 when the USCG Eagle put into New York City.